# Bash search of files containing some keys combined in a Boolean expression

Tags: bash, search, logical-operators, boolean-expression

Given a number of JSON files in a directory, I need to extract the names of those that contain, in a line labeled `"keyword:"`, a combination of words that match a Boolean query.

For example:

file `01` contains the line:

```
...
  "keyword": "Alabama", "Washington"
...
```

file `02` contains the line:

```
...
  "keyword": "Washington", "Pennsylvania"
...
```

this is how the search should work:

```
$ query "Washington"
01
02

$ query "Washington & !Alabama"
02

$ query "Alabama | Pennsylvania"
01
02
```

and so on, for any Boolean combination of individual keys, say

```
query "(Alabama & !California) | Maine"
```

`grep "keyword" <directory>` will extract the lines of interest, and the rest can be pipelined from there, but `grep` implementations of logical operators differ much from Boolean expressions, and `awk`, while getting closer in its syntax, doesn't seem to work for me (may be I haven't dedicated enough time to it).

What would be a good candidate to implement this functionality, and how to translate to such an intuitive syntax?

Comment: Have you tried `jq`?

Comment: @codeforester not really, first time I've heard of it. On one hand, I have reasons to make it with core commands, as it will run on clients that do not have `jq` installed; on the other, I might be dealing with many thousands on files, and the script running on old and limited systems. I understand that these commands will outperform `jq`. (Still, it's no problem if the query takes a few seconds.)

Comment: It's perfectly valid for JSON files to be all one line or have line breaks after `"keyword":`. `jq` will treat these files correctly, while `grep` will just fail

Comment: My approach would be to make sure all systems have `sqlite3` installed. You maintain a `sqlite` index of those several thousand files and run your queries against it, using SQL. There is __no__ need to re-implement yet another buggy parser. Going my way, you would separate indexing from querying, and you could reimplement the indexer in several languages (bash, python, jq...) to find what best suits your needs, without disrupting the query part.

Comment: @thatotherguy `jq` seems to be the tool. Problem is that the files are not  RFC7159 compliant (newlines and LaTeX special characters abound), so `jq` cannot process them unless they're escaped.